awk optimizar generacion de archivo txt formateado
Procesando un txt para obtener una data en especifico, se generan 3 archivos separados que contienen una lista como sigue:

descripción (*PAPEL)
cantidad (#3,00)
Precio Unitario (~10,0000)

Esto se generan "n" cantidad de veces el contenido del txt en renglones linea por linea en cada archivo, (es de acotar que las lineas contentivas de los datos generados en archivodatos.txt para cada renglón se marca esa linea con un caracter distinto al inicio "~" precio "#" cantidad "*" descripcion), de esta manera se logra filtrar y formatear correctamente con los siguientes comandos:
###====Genera precios de productos de venta formateado a 10 dígitos (8enteros,2 decimales) con relleno de ceros a la izquierda y sin punto o coma decimal 1234567800.
awk '/^~/ {gsub("Bs.","");gsub(",0000",",00");print $2}' archivodatos.txt | awk -F ',' '{ printf("%08d00\n", $0) }' > precio.txt

###====Genera cantidad de venta
awk '/^#/ {gsub("h","");print $2}'  archivodatos.txt| awk -F ',' '{ printf("%05d000\n", $0) }' > cantidad.txt'''

###==== Genera descripción de producto
awk '/^*/ {print "|"$2"|"}' archivodatos.txt > descripcion.txt

###====Genera cuerpo de la factura
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{print a[FNR],$0}' 1precio.info 2cantidad.info > tmp.txt

awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{gsub(" ", "");print a[FNR],$0}' tmp.txt 3descripcion.info | awk '{gsub(" ","");print}' > renglones.txt

Agradecería me ayudaran a optimizar el código de ser posible compactarlo al máximo para la emisión final de renglones.txt, con menos pasos y lineas de awk.
La salida final de cada línea en renglones.txt según el ejemplo queda así:
000000100000003000|PAPEL|
